# Is it possible to built a redirect link that redirects you depending on your user group?

Tags: 2010, hyperlink, redirect

I want to built a link that you click and depending on your user group it redirects you to a certain page. Is the same possible for a redirect page?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- You can use different ContentEditor (Script) WebParts for Each Group, set the **[Target Audience](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/target-audiences-of-web-parts-in-sharepoint/)** on each WebPart to match your groups.
- Inside each Webpart add a script which sets a global `_MyGroupName` variable

  ```
  _MyGroupName='A';
  ```
- Add a ContentEditor Webpart at the bottom of the page which executes code for everyone

  ```
  switch(_MyGroupName){
   case('A'): url='';
      break;
   case('B'): url='';
      break;
   case('C'): url='';
      break;
  }
  document.location=url;
  ```